# Hotfile-like File Hosting service in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload

The company that I work for has recently assigned me the task of building a File-Hosting service for them which should work in a similar manner as Hotfile/Mediafire/etc. It needs to have all of their features such as download speed limiting for normal users, high speed downloads for premium users, waiting before downloads etc.

The main problem I'm facing is how should I limit speed for my normal users. We have a lot of data (around 30TB) and more and more is being uploaded each day. What would be the ideal way to store these files and serve them to our users?

I want to implement it in Ruby on Rails and plan on using Paperclip, Mongoid and Nginx.

Comment: You're starting with the wrong approach. You know the problem, you don't know the solution, but you decide in advance the language and even the libraries. Who's telling you that these technologies may help you to solve the problem? You should thing about a solution *first*, *then* select the best technology/language/tools to implement it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is really vague. Stack Overflow isn't for helping you design your site, only for answering specific technical questions. That said, here's how I would do it:

- store your files in non-public S3 (under arbitrary timestamp/GUIDS)
- Premium users are given direct access to the file on S3 via time-limited signed links (RoR authenticates, then sends 302 redirect to the signed link)
- For not-so-premium users, they will use nginx to proxy to a signed link (they never see the actual S3 link)
- Use the X-Sendfile feature so that Rails can be "in the loop" on every requests, but still offload file serving/proxying to nginx.
- the different classes of users would have different internal locations, all proxying to S3. RoR decides which class, then puts a signed link into the Sendfile header for nginx to serve.
- I'm no expert on PaperClip, but unless it supports what you are doing, it will probably get in the way more than it helps.
- If all files are "public", don't bother storing them in a DB. Just have nginx serve a friendly error page if not found in S3. (Yes, you'll be signing links to nowhere, which eats a little CPU. But it will save your database from becoming a bottleneck.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. And I'll try to post better questions in the future.